# Symfony 5 pass parameter to logout / login functions

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-security, symfony5

In a Symfony 5.0 Application I have the following scenario:

An admin user is able to create new users.
If a new user is created in that way I want to log out the admin redirect to the login screen and set the prefilled value in the email field to the one of the user created just before.

Currently I have a link with `href="{{ path('app_logout', {email: user.email}) }}"`
I the SecurityController I got the default logout method defined like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
 */
public function logout()
{
    throw new \Exception('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall');
}
```

So... how would I be able to process the "email"-parameter and pass it on to the login function to handle it there?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Injection to get the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` object, then get the `email` parameter from there:

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->get('email') {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login', [
            'email' => $request->get('email');
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
 */
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        // force logout of previous user
        $tokenStorage->setToken(null);

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        $form = $this->createForm(LoginForm::class, [
            'email' => $request->get('email');
        ]);

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: yeah - but how? I have no idea on how to pass parameter to the login-function as the app_logout method (pasted in my post) is not being called by the default logout / login procedure.

Comment: You can do it the same way. See my revised answer for a suggestion. The default code is yours to modify to your needs. My code is not tested, so tweak as needed for your application.

Comment: OK. I was thinking about that too. But - won't I break the security system behaviour if I override the logout method doing nothing then redirecting? I don't expect a proper logout then...

Comment: See one more change to my answer. In the login() script, I force logout of the user with the added `tokenStorage->setToken(null)`, and of course DI is used to inject the `TokenStorageInterface` to make this work.

Comment: I don't think this will break security since as you mentioned `logout()` is not being called natively, but since you are explicity calling the function with your link and then forcing logout of the user with the `setToken(null)` method, you should be good.